# Ali express automation with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, aliexpress

I am working at Aliexpress automation with selenium and python, now stuck here, the problem is I am not finding any selector for the order quantity button, to increase the quantity according to the user choice, as incircled below in the image. I have tried class name but didn't work, if anyone knows the solution plz comment.
link to the page is given:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002611164689.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.2fec7741zQOW1u&algo_pvid=null&algo_expid=null&btsid=0b0a555d16226644016931040e3512&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_
tried code:

```
quantity=driver.find_element_by_class_name("next-btn next-medium next-btn-normal").click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class name you used returns 2 buttons and not one. Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='next-input-group-addon next-after']/button").click()
```

Comment: worked, plz also for the "buy now " button.

Comment: can you share what you have tried for the buy now button?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name('info-buy-now').click()

Comment: there is no such class found. where should i look for this Buy now button?

Comment: here is link:   https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002611164689.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.2fec7741zQOW1u&algo_pvid=null&algo_expid=null&btsid=0b0a555d16226644016931040e3512&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603

Comment: following code work for 'buy now':       'driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class ='buy-now-wrap']/button").click()'